# Prints are too dark when printing from computer, but not from SD card

Tags: printing, color-management, os-x, epson

I have a weird problem. I have an Epson XP 820 printer, brand new. I have been trying to print photographs and running into a problem where the printed photo (printed from photoshop or picasa or preview) is much darker than the one on the screen. I thought it was a monitor calibration problem. HOWEVER, when I print the same file directly from the SD card insert on the printer, it prints out exactly as bright as it appears on the computer monitor. So this seems to be a problem between the computer and the printer. Anyone ever hear of this before?

I have a MacBook Pro running Yosemite 10.10.2 (14C109).

Thanks in advance for any ideas.

Comment: It sounds like a driver issue...In some cases you can modify how your data is sent to the printer, but I'm no expert in the field.

Comment: Check the **Color Matching** section on the print options page when printing and see what the settings are. I've an older Epson Stylus Pro 4000 which brings up two options, **ColorSync** and **EPSON Color Controls**. What's yours currently set to?

Comment: BTW, I find the Epson printer settings do not "stick" if when set from the *Properties* page accessed from the standard *Print* dialog. The defaults can be set from the *Control Panel* or from the Epson printer utility.

Comment: Are you sure the printer isn't using some form of *auto correction* when printing directly from the SD card?

Comment: I've checked and your printer has the same Color Matching options as mine. Additionally you will find a Color Options section, have a play with the options here (Manual Settings/Fix Photo/Off) and see what happens...

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your print settings in OS X may have been modified to an undesirable setting.  Try re-adding the Epson XP 820 printer to OS X, naming it something different than your existing one, and try printing with that one.

1. Choose Apple menu > System Preferences, then click Printers & Scanners.
2. Click the "+" under the list on the left to Add a Printer and select the appropriate method for how your printer is connected.

You can also try resetting the printer system by:

1. Choose Apple menu > System Preferences, then click Printers & Scanners.
2. Hold down the Control key as you click in the list at the left, then choose “Reset printing system” from the menu that appears.

After you reset the printing system, all of your printers in Printers & Scanners preferences will be gone and you will need to re-add.  Before you reset the printing system, you may want to try adding